# Debug SVC WCF and ASP.NET Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I'm new to that project as well as WCF and look for a way to properly debug the project using regular breakpoints.

*Given are 2 solutions:*

1. ASP.NET Project in: **Solution 'Projects'**
2. WCF Project in: **Solution 'ProjectService'**

in my 1st solution *Solution 'Projects'* I'm calling the WCF Service the following way:

```
OperationResult<FindProjectsResult> projectsResult = _projectsWcfService.Call(p => p.FindProjects())
```

and reference the Wcf in the *Web.config* file:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="/ProjectSearch.svc" binding="NamedPipeBinding" name="ProjectServiceNetNamedPipe">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

The implementation for my Wcf Service is in the 2nd solution **Solution 'ProjectService'** in my svc file `ProjectSearch.svc.cs`.

The method I'm calling from solution 1 looks like that:

```
public OperationResult<FindProjectsResponse> FindProjects()
{
    return ProjectManagement.FindProjects();
}
```

It all works fine.

I need to know, how to debug the WCF Service.

Currently I'm attaching solution 1 to my `w3wp.exe` process. Though I cannot attach 2 solutions on 1 process.

I would be fine with any help on how to debug the WCF service.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Wouldn't there be 2 w3wp.exe processes?

Comment: thanks, solved ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the solution, you can configure your solution so that you can debug multiple projects via visual studio.

[image]

Comment: @john.1020 mark answer please if it solves your problem. cheers :)